# Reverse comment sorting order in Vimeo

Tags: comments, vimeo

It's one of those small things that is driving me nuts - how do you reverse the sorting order of comments on Vimeo videos so that new comments come in first instead of last?

I can easily (as I assume others would already have) write a simple userscript that does this, but I just need to make sure there isn't something obvious which I missed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've written the script to do this. [Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/90148.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/90148)

> #### [Vimeo Comment Order Reverser](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/90148)
>
> This simple script reverses the order 
>   of Vimeo comments so that the
>   top comment will be the most recent
>   instead of the oldest. It will attempt
>   to load more comments if possible
>   (because the oldest comments will only
>   be available for reverse when they're
>   loaded), which may cause video pages
>   with large amount of comments to
>   become more sluggish on slower
>   computers.
>
> This will not work on Internet
>   Explorer because it uses DOM functions
>   which are not available on poor old IE.
>
> Comment on code quality and other optimisation are very welcome.